# How to use this CSS code in React JS without any new dependencies?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to create a green pulse in the body when a User completes an action in a React JS, to improve the end-user experience. However, I am having trouble doing so.

I have tried to reference the css style and apply it to them HTML element

```js
import styles from './styles/styles.less';

handleSuccess(){
  const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  body.style = styles.body;
}
```

`styles.less`

```
body {
  background-color: white;
  animation-name: color;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@keyframes color {
  0% {
    background-color: #DEFAE8;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: #62EB96;
  }
  100 {
    background-color: #91F1B5;
  }
}
```

I have seen similar solutions stating to install the '[styled-components](https://styled-components.com/)' package, but as mentioned, I think this is possible through the styling options available.

Is it possible to use `@keyframes` in React.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest having a class for your body when success occurs.

```css
body.success {
 ...
 animation-name: color;
 animation-duration: 2s;
 animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

You can then toggle the class depending on what state you need your website to be in.

```js
handleSuccess() {
 document.body.classList.add("success");
 document.body.addEventListener("animationend", () => {
   document.body.classList.remove("success");
 });
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/body-animation-7zoxi?file=/src/App.js:77-226)

PS: You're missing a `%` after the `100` in your `@keyframes`

Answer (score 3):

You can a reference to the body with just `document.body`, no need for `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];`

You can create a class called body-pulse and attach it to the body on handleSuccess().

```
  handleSuccess() {
    document.body.classList.add("body-pulse")
  }
```

```
@keyframes color {
  0% {
    background-color: #defae8;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: #62eb96;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #91f1b5;
  }
}

.body-pulse {
  background-color: white;
  animation-name: color;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-dust-4lbv0?file=/src/styles.css